# Map behavior like in Google Maps application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I want to achive map behavior like in google maps application. Example: set marker on a shop somewhere in the bottom of the screen, click on that marker so info panel should open and overlay the marker, map moves it's content so marker is still visible. I don't know how to correctly quote this requirement so I've found nothing on that point in the internet. Is there any guide on this UI pattern?

[image: marker in the bottom][image: map moves to show the marker]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you google it, you will find a lot of code and documentation regarding it. Please visit the link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

you can start from here
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

you will find it very close to your requirement

Comment: Thanks a lot. What I need is setPadding() method.

Answer (score 0):

you can set your content in info window API reference is here

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows

Comment: info windows is not what I need.

Comment: will you explain in detail what you need ?

Comment: Look at two screenshots in my post. If I knew how to correctly make a request for this feature I would find the guide myself.

Comment: i can't understand your requirement from screen shot because it is in chinese langugage